# Winning possiblities in 3D tic-tac-toe

Tags: statistics

How many ways to get 3 in a row are there in a $3 \times 3 \times 3$ tic-tac-toe game? I arrived at 49, but I'm not sure if there are more of them.

Comment: By "winning possibility", do you mean a sequence of moves that leads to Player 1's victory (or Player 2's)?

Comment: You need to be more specific than that. Do you mean possible setting at the end of the game? The entire play of the game? Does have to be a setting achievable only through a play following all the rules (number of "x" and "o" differs at most by one? What about symmetries? Please, be more specific and also describe the possibilities you found. Plus in 3D, its a 3x3x3

Comment: It might help clarify the question if you say what the answer is in ordinary, 2d tic tac toe.

Comment: i mean that how many possibilities are there in order to win a 3d 3x3 tic tac toe game for eg a 2d 3x3 tic tac toe has 8 winninig possibilities.3 rows ,3 columns and 2 diagonals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each of the three horizontal planes, there are eight combinations. There are also nine vertical columns, and eight vertical planes (four outer and four inner ones) in which two diagonals can be drawn. Indeed, the number of combinations 
$n$ equals:

$$n = 24 + 9 + 8 \cdot 2 = 49$$

A second way to solve this is by distinguishing four different types of points:

1. A vertex, which contributes to 7 line segments;
2. A corner on an edge, which contributes to 4 line segments;
3. The middle of a facet, which contributes to 5 line segments;
4. The center of the cube, which contributes to 13 line segments.

Since we counted each line segment thrice, we find:

$$n = \frac{8 \cdot 7 + 12 \cdot 4 + 6 \cdot 5 + 13}{3} = \frac{147}{3} = 49$$

Answer (score 1):

- $3 \times 3 \times 3$ simple rows or columns parallel to edges
- $3 \times 3 \times 2$ diagonals on planes parallel to faces
- $4$ diagonals between pairs of opposite vertices

making the same $49$ in total as jvdhooft found